# How to send axios request to localhost?

Tags: javascript, django, axios, expo

I am currently trying to send an API request from a mobile app to a django server running on my computer. I am receiving a network error every time I try and send the request, regardless of the different headers I use (I am new to this so my headers could be totally wrong).

Here is the request I am sending:

```
export async function requestPrediction(img) {
  const url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/v1/predict/';

  const data = new FormData();

  data.append('file', {
    uri: img,
    type: 'image/jpeg',
    name: 'imageName'
  });

  try {
    console.log(url, data);
    let resp = await Axios.post(url, data, {
      headers: {
        'accept': 'application/json',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
        'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${data._boundary}`,
      }
    });
    console.log('######################\n','ACTION_RESULTS_SUCCESS',resp.data);
  } catch(error) {
    console.log('######################\n','ACTION_RESULTS_ERROR', error);
  }
}
```

I am pretty certain the URL I am sending to is the right address. When I type that URL in on my computer while the server is running I do not receive an error that the page wasn't found. Thanks for the help. I can post any server-side code that might be necessary.

Comment: Is the mobile app running on your computer on your actual mobile?

Comment: my actual mobile device, I am using react native expo.

Comment: This address `'http://127.0.0.1'` can only be accessed by your computer. To access your Django server from your mobile device you need to use your computer's IP address with that port

Comment: ah that makes sense, any idea where I can go to find that out?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: iOS for mobile, mac for computer

Comment: do i need to change the url in the request from the phone?

Comment: No, in your code. See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This address `'http://127.0.0.1'` can only be accessed by your computer.

To access your Django server from your mobile device you need to use your computer's IP address with that port

Make sure your mobile is connected to the same Wifi as your computer.

Replace `'http://127.0.0.1'` with your IP address

so it looks something like this

`https://IP_ADDRESS:8000/v1/predict/'`

Follow this [guide](https://www.hellotech.com/guide/for/how-to-find-ip-address-on-mac) to find your Mac's IP address

Comment: hmmm. I did exactly that and am still getting the same error

Comment: Should work! Just make sure your django server is running, and your mobile is connected on the same wifi as your computer. Also, consider restarting/rebuilding your project

Comment: Are you using any VPN proxy?

Comment: It should be the public ip address correct? I just tried that and am no longer getting a network issue

Comment: No, no vpn proxy

Comment: Try this guide [Find your local IP address on a Mac](https://www.avg.com/en/signal/find-ip-address#:~:text=Open%20the%20Apple%20menu%20and,be%20displayed%20in%20the%20middle.)

Comment: using my public ipv4 address found here: https://www.whatismyip.com/ actually solved the issue and i received an ACTION_RESULTS_SUCCESS. Thank you for your help.

Comment: oh crap wait a second. It looks like it just sent it to my ISP, it didn't actually send the data to the server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230777/discussion-between-fortunee-and-goolius-boozler).

Comment: I sent you the logs when you have a chance